# how to create relationship between tables in ruby on rails ie patient table userid depends on user table id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables. One for `users` and one for `patients`.

The `users` table has the following columns:

> - userid,
> - name,
> - email,
> - password

And `patients` table has the following columns:

> - userid,
> - phone,
> - age

The `userid` column in `patients` table depends on `userid` of `users` table.

My question is how to create a relation between these two tables. I am new to ruby on rails. Please help me.

Comment: If you are new to rails, I highly recommend reading through the official Rails Guides. Start here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html It will explain exactly what you need... which is an Association... but read it all. Then you'll know it inside and out.

Comment: sir i already read it please tell me this

Comment: 1) I am not a sir. 2) If you read my first comment you will see I already said you need an association... if you have read the guide on Active Record Associations you will find what you need.

Comment: actually i m new to stackexchange so i thought it was prakash murthy who is commenting so sorry for sir and i'll  read it later thanks for commenting ma'am

Comment: No problems :) Reading all of the rails guides will really help you learn this stuff very well. it is time well spent.